# PHP foreach loop not working properly - dies after half array iteration

Tags: php, simplexml, simple-html-dom

In this script i am loading an URL, that has 80 items. With the help of simple_html_dom iterating for each item 'tr' which is total of 80.

But foreach loop iterating only 42 items in the following code.

```
<?php
include_once "simple_html_dom.php";
$job_links=array();
$main_url = "http://xyz.com/rescnt=80";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($main_url);
$fun = $html->find('div[class=dontent_wrap]',0)->find('table',0);
$i=0;
echo count($fun->find('tr'));
foreach($fun->find('tr') as $tr){
    echo ++$i;
    $td = $tr->find( 'td',1);
    $a =  $td->find('a',0);
    $link = $a->href;
    $id = $a->id;
        $id = trim(preg_replace('/link/','',$id)); 
     $my_link ="http://xyz.com/details/".$id.".html";
    if(strpos($link, $my_link)!==false){
        $job_links[] =trim($my_link);

    }
}
echo 'count:'.count($job_links);
print_r($job_links);
?>
```

On removing few lines from the loop it is iterating complete to 81.

```
foreach($fun->find('tr') as $tr){
    echo ++$i;
    $td = $tr->find( 'td',1);
}
```

I don't know what's going wrong. It already took my day.

It is not issue of timeout because i used `set_time_limit(0);` not working.

If the number of items  "tr" redured to 40 then the loop is iterating to 21 again same problem (it also tells there is no issue of timeout)

All items are identical, have same types and same number of elements.

Comment: Are any errors being thrown? That could explain why it is only getting half way through.

Comment: @Pudge601 No, it is not throwing any error. It simple stop working further executing

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in .... on line 14. Line 14:  $a =  $td->find('a',0); Maybe this could help?

Comment: @nevermin thanks how to detect it and how do i avoid it

Comment: .have you tried doing `$array_tr=$fun->find('tr');` and then doing the foreach using this variable?

Comment: you should probably check if `$td = $tr->find( 'td',1);` returned anything before doing `$a =  $td->find('a',0);`

Comment: @Naryl `$array_tr=$fun->find('tr');` not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One td is missing from html, it seems, so:

```
 include("simple_html_dom.php");
$job_links=array();
$monster_main_url = "http://jobsearch.monsterindia.com/searchresult.html?day=1&res_cnt=80";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($monster_main_url);
$fun = $html->find('div[class=dd_content_wrap]',0)->find('table',0);
$i=0;
echo count($fun->find('tr'));

foreach($fun->find('tr') as $tr){
    echo ++$i;


    $td = $tr->find( 'td',1);
    if($td!=NULL) {
    $a =  $td->find('a',0);


    $link = $a->href;
    $id = $a->id;
        $id = trim(preg_replace('/link/','',$id)); 
     $my_link ="http://jobs.monsterindia.com/details/".$id.".html";
    }

    else {

        $my_link="no link";

    }
    if(strpos($link, $my_link)!==false){
        $job_links[] =trim($my_link);

    }
}
echo '<br>count:'.count($job_links);
print_r($job_links);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn errors on:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Put that right at the beginning of your file.